# What is the correct way to bind a Jquery click event to a dynamically inserted div in Phonegap?

Tags: click, cordova, jquery

I'm trying to bind a click event to a dynamically inserted div within a iOS Phonegap app.
The HTML/jQuery is functioning normal within a browser, but won't function in the build app.

What is the correct way to bind a Jquery click event to a dynamically inserted div in Phonegap?

I tried

```
$(document).on("click","#div",function() { });  

$("#div").on("click","#div",function() { });  

$("#div").live("click",function() { });
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide your code for us to have a look?

Comment: See edited original post! Thanks!

Comment: @MarkdeVries Why are you using .div? '.' is used for class, use only 'div' or else use '#divId'

Comment: Does it matter for the question? In this case the class is used only once.

Comment: I changed the class to an ID and the still click event doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkdeVries can you post a jsfiddle for this and reproduce the problem?

Comment: I will do that, problem is, that it does work in a browser, but not in the Phonegap app.

Comment: Here you go! Like I said, it is working in a browser, but not when the html is part of a Phonegap iOS app. http://jsfiddle.net/ehWAx/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("click","#newDiv",function () {

//some code here
});
```

or use :

```
$(document).on("click","div",function () {

    //some code here
    });
```